# How to exec a pod in kubernetes in a shell script if the pod name changes with every deployment

Tags: shell, kubernetes, exec

Same pods with every deployment get a different name so how to put this in shell scripts so that we can exec it to pods without changing the script with every deployment

deployed 1st time

NAMESPACE          NAME                                        READY

default       call-f6f8cfd84-5l6zv                             3/3

depolyed 2nd time

default       call-7gcfrd45d-264df                             3/3

tried multiple ways but not working

Comment: This is one of the reasons to avoid `kubectl exec` unless you really need it as a debugging tool.  What are you trying to do with `kubectl exec`, and can you set up the container to do it on its own?

Answer (score 0):

You can exec into statefulset/deployment or other k8s workloads too. This will let you exec into the first pod deployed by the workload. The following example shows how to exec into the first pod deployed by the statefulset `db-cluster` in `demo` namespace in interactive mode using bash shell. I hope this helps!

```
kubectl exec -it -n demo sts/db-cluster -- bash
```